# What is a WebSocket Subprotocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Ive been trying to implement the WebSocket protocol from scratch in nodejs, doing so i have a question thats since been unawnsered. What exactly are subprotocols in regards to websockets? The second parameter of the WebSocket constructor is where you specify "subprotocols" -

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000",["http",...]);
```

Can anybody give me a clear awnser to what purpose they have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Websockets just define a mechanism to exchange arbitrary messages. What those messages *mean*, what kind of messages a client can expect at any particular point in time or what messages they are allowed to send is entirely up to the implementing application. So you need an agreement between the server and client about these things. You might say… you need a *protocol specification*. The subprotocol parameter simply lets clients formally exchange this information. You can just make up any name for any protocol you want. The server can simply check that the client appears to adhere to that protocol during the handshake. You can also use it to request different kinds of protocols from the server, or use it for versioning (e.g. when you introduce `my-protocol-v2`, but still need to support clients only understanding `my-protocol-v1`).

Comment: Ok, i see how that makes sence. So for example, say my client had two ways of parsing and evaluating messages based on two different situations, so on the client side i sent over a subprotocol for one of those specific ways based on the clients needs, so on the server side i implemented those protocols. But when my server receives a Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header, it will use the specified subprotocol. Would that be a valid senario/interpretation?

Comment: To make that a little more concrete, your server might support sending messages encoded in JSON or XML. The client can tell the server which methods it supports, and the server can then pick one and agree to that particular subprotocol. — Or, you could use that to signal what kinds of messages the client expects to get and/or send. Or any other custom use you can think of that helps the client and server negotiate a particular set of rules of how they'll communicate.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for putting it into perspective for me!

Comment: What's the rule on 'who' identifies the available sub-protocols? From what I read, it looks like the client has the power in declaring the sub-protocols. How does the client know the server even supports `myObsecureServerProtocolFormat` vs `json` or `xml` on initial connection attempt if the server doesn't define them. In my mind the server would communicate the available sub-protocols and then client would have to choose from them.

Comment: @Reahreic Presumably you know what kind of server you're connecting to when you write the code for the client…!? You're not going to connect to random unknown web socket servers of which you have no clue what protocol they speak or what data they'll send. In this sense, this is a sanity and permission check for the server as well; it can be sure the client will have at least a general idea that it's connecting to the right server and isn't just a random bot.

Answer (score 6):

Explained on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#subprotocols)

> Think of a subprotocol as a custom XML schema or doctype declaration.
> You're still using XML and its syntax, but you're additionally
> restricted by a structure you agreed on. WebSocket subprotocols are
> just like that. They do not introduce anything fancy, they just
> establish structure. Like a doctype or schema, both parties must agree
> on the subprotocol; unlike a doctype or schema, the subprotocol is
> implemented on the server and cannot be externally referred to by the
> client.
>
> *Subprotocols are explained in sections 1.9, 4.2, 11.3.4, and 11.5 of the spec.*
>
> A client has to ask for a specific subprotocol. To do so, it will send
> something like this as part of the original handshake:
>
> `http GET /chat HTTP/1.1 ... Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: soap, wamp`
>
> or, equivalently:
>
> `... Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: soap Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp`
>
> Now the server must pick one of the protocols that the client
> suggested and it supports. If there is more than one, send the first
> one the client sent. Imagine our server can use both soap and wamp.
> Then, in the response handshake, it sends:
>
> `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: soap`
>
> The server can't send more than one Sec-Websocket-Protocol header. If
> the server doesn't want to use any subprotocol, it shouldn't send any
> Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header. Sending a blank header is incorrect.
> The client may close the connection if it doesn't get the subprotocol
> it wants.
>
> If you want your server to obey certain subprotocols, then naturally
> you'll need extra code on the server. Let's imagine we're using a
> subprotocol json. In this subprotocol, all data is passed as JSON. If
> the client solicits this protocol and the server wants to use it, the
> server needs to have a JSON parser. Practically speaking, this will be
> part of a library, but the server needs to pass the data around.

Answer (score 2):

Some sample code, **copy from** https://hpbn.co/websocket/#subprotocol-negotiation, to make it clear.

> The client can advertise which protocols it supports to the server as
> part of its initial connection handshake:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/socket',
                       ['appProtocol', 'appProtocol-v2']); 

ws.onopen = function () {
  if (ws.protocol == 'appProtocol-v2') { 
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```